# BeautifulSoup output contains spaces after .strip()

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the following code.

```
html = urllib2.urlopen(
    'https://ebet.tab.co.nz/results/CHCG-reslt05070400.html').read()


soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
data = soup.findAll('div', {'class' : 'header bold'})
match = re.search('R', data[0].text)
race_title = data[0].text[(match.start()):]
race_title = str(race_title.strip(' \t\n\r'))
print race_title
```

The output I get on the screen in the console is below

```
Race 1 PEDIGREE ADVANCE SPRINT
                C0
                295 m
```

I thought strip would get rid of any type of spaces between SPRINT and C0 but obviously I am missing something so I need help understanding this result. Is it because the bs4 output the string in unicode or something?

Comment: do you want to remove all the spaces?

Comment: I want an output string of the form, "Race 1 PEDIGREE ADVANCE SPRINT C0 295 m"

Comment: so you want to remove the newlines? use `race_title.replace("\n","")`. read the docs for all this info : http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strip()` removes only leading or trailing characters. if you want to remove the newlines you should use `replace("\n","")`

Comment: Ah thanks, but I think there are tabs and newlines and spaces between some of the words. Just use 3 .replace() statements or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You could use a regular expression to replace a range of characters. like this : `re.sub('345','999','123456')
'129996'`

Answer (score 2):

Usually STRIP only strips spaces at the beginning and the end of the string.
Use STR_REPLACE to replace space with "".

> strip(    s[, chars]) Return a copy of the string with leading and
>   trailing characters removed. If chars is omitted or None, whitespace
>   characters are removed. If given and not None, chars must be a string;
>   the characters in the string will be stripped from the both ends of
>   the string this method is called on. Changed in version 2.2.3: The
>   chars parameter was added. The chars parameter cannot be passed in
>   earlier 2.2 versions.